# Incrementing File Names

Tags: visual-block

I'm hoping to create a [.cl](http://www.twilightlandscapes.com/IRAFtutorial/IRAFintro_04.html) script to run in [IRAF](http://iraf.noao.edu/).  I have a list of spectra on which I want to run [dispcor](http://stsdas.stsci.edu/cgi-bin/gethelp.cgi?dispcor).  I was wondering if there's an easy way to paste the output file names with incrementing numbers.  The lines look like this:

```
dispcor extracted_ori5_r1.0001.fits calibrated_ori5_r1.0001.fits
```

I want the output file name to increase (`.0001`, `.0002`, etc.).  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So by "paste the output file names," do you mean that you need to paste text to a file, or do you want to actually *generate* the new files?

Comment: I just need to add the "calibrated_ori5_r1.0xxx.fits" to the end of each line in the text file with incrementing numbers.  I will then run this cl script in IRAF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting point:

```
dispcor extracted_ori5_r1.0001.fits calibrated_ori5_r1.0001.fits
```

1. Start recording in register `a`:

   ```
   qa
   ```
2. Yank the line:

   ```
   yy
   ```
3. Put it right under the current line:

   ```
   p
   ```
4. Move the cursor to the first `0001`:

   ```
   f.l
   ```
5. Increment the number:

   ```
   <C-a>
   ```
6. Move the cursor to the next `0001`:

   ```
   ;;l
   ```
7. Increment again:

   ```
   .
   ```
8. Stop recording:

   ```
   q
   ```
9. Play it back 23 times:

   ```
   23@a
   ```

In short:

```
qayypf.l<C-a>;;l.q
23@a
```

Result:

```
dispcor extracted_ori5_r1.0001.fits calibrated_ori5_r1.0001.fit
dispcor extracted_ori5_r1.0002.fits calibrated_ori5_r1.0002.fit
dispcor extracted_ori5_r1.0003.fits calibrated_ori5_r1.0003.fit
dispcor extracted_ori5_r1.0004.fits calibrated_ori5_r1.0004.fit
dispcor extracted_ori5_r1.0005.fits calibrated_ori5_r1.0005.fit
dispcor extracted_ori5_r1.0006.fits calibrated_ori5_r1.0006.fit
dispcor extracted_ori5_r1.0007.fits calibrated_ori5_r1.0007.fit
dispcor extracted_ori5_r1.0008.fits calibrated_ori5_r1.0008.fit
dispcor extracted_ori5_r1.0009.fits calibrated_ori5_r1.0009.fit
[...]
dispcor extracted_ori5_r1.0025.fits calibrated_ori5_r1.0025.fit
```

Comment: Need to be a little careful with this. I'm not sure why I'm getting a different result than you, but because of the leading zero's when I do this my `<C-a>` assumes octal numbers and increments as such.

Comment: @Tumbler41 Try `:set nrformats-=octal`

Comment: @DJMcMayhem fair enough, but default behavior is to treat it as octal. So reader be wary.

Comment: @Tumbler41 this default is going to be changed (or did already with the latest Vim release)

Comment: Yes you probably can. Could you add a sample to your question?

Comment: Sure...I'm new to this.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a different solution.
Copy the line: `yy`, paste 23 times: `23p`, go to the **second** line: `:2`, Move to the `0001`: `$F1`, block select the range you want to be incremented `<ctrl>vGh`, increment each number sequentially: `g<ctrl-a>`

This needs a relative recent Vim, something like 7.4.1000 should do it.

Read the help at `:h g_Ctrl-A`

Comment: I forgot to mention.  I already have a list of the extracted files, and they skip around (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, etc.).  Is there a way to use the same number that is found at the beginning of the line at the end of the line?

Comment: @catclark i don't understand the question